# Karate - How to compare shuffled json with response?

Tags: json, karate, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to compare response with expected json stored already as a file. There are few elements in response where the order is different in response. Tried below code but still failing:

```
def expected_response = read('classpath:api/template/test.json')
```

`And match response == '#(^*expected_response)'`

Also tried 
 `And match response contains any expected_response`

Both cases error comes as actual does not contains expected. Kindly help to resolve.

Comment: Have also tried   And match response == '#(^^expected_response)'. This also fails

Comment: Could you provide some test.json file (after you remove confidential data)? Also, what is shuffled? Is it that some objects are in a different order inside of an array for example?

Comment: The [order of elements in match](https://github.com/intuit/karate#payload-assertions--smart-comparison) should not matter. If so, open an issue.

Also, it would be great to have [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).